# Mobile nav not clickable

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm trying to make a responsive website with a dropdown mobile navbar, the menu opens but when you try to click it it closes immediately.

I also noticed that when viewed on the android version of chrome, there's a gap between the navbar and the actual menu.

I can't wrap my head around it and have no idea to fix it.

My JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/91t2hp3p/1/

Code:

```
<div class="nav animated slideInDown">
       <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-256.png" alt="" class="hamburger">
       <ul id="menu">
           <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
           <li><a href="#aboutme">ABOUT ME</a></li>
           <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
           <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
       </ul>

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    line-height: 10vh;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.nav .hamburger {
    display: none;
}

.nav .logo h1 {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 32px;
}

.nav ul {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;

}

.nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}

.nav ul a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: #999;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 850px){
    .up {
        margin-right: 8px;
    }

    .nav .hamburger {
        height: 6vh;
        width: 6vh;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        margin: 2vh 0 0 2vh;
    }

    .nav ul {
        visibility: hidden;
        float: none;
        padding-top: 10vh;
        display: block;
    }

    .nav .hamburger:hover ~ ul {
        visibility: visible;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .nav ul li {
        display: block;
        background-color: #F2F2F2;
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: You currently have the navigation menu only visible on hover. Is this intentional? What is the **desired** behaviour? One click to open the menu, then another click to close it?

Comment: My goal is to let it open when you click it and close it on another click. It also automatically has to close when you click a link. My problem right now (on mobile) is that when you click it, it opens but doesn't stay persistent.

Comment: When I click the icon in Chrome at a mobile width, the menu does nothing; you have no JavaScript causing the menu to open or close. Instead, the menu simply appears when I hover over the icon. This cannot be solved without JavaScript; do you have access to it?

Comment: Yes, I have JQuery linked.

Comment: Not in your JSFiddle you don't. Please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that **clearly** explains the **exact** problem you are facing.

Comment: I do have access to it, but I'm not using it for the nav. Including my whole page would mean 200 lines of html, 500 css and 150 js. Anyway, I've updated the fiddle with the used javascript

Answer (score 0):

Toggle a class when `.hamburger` is clicked via JavaScript and react to this class in CSS.

```
$('.hamburger').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#menu').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

In CSS toggle the visibility of the menu:

```
#menu.visible {
    display: block;
}
```